# Search a large set of dom elements for string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, cordova

I have a question on the best way of searching a large set of DOM elements for a string. The situation is that there is a JSON object with say products & serial numbers. Using this JSON object a list gets build consisting of divs, which can be scrolled through. My initial approach was to store the JSON object in localStorage and search localStorage however on ipad the JSON object seems to be stored incorrectly in localstorage even using `JSON.stringify` to set it and `JSON.parse` to retrieve it.

I am running a phonegap app on ipad and would like the user to be able to search the collection of items to find any items matching a certain amount of characters on the serial number.

The divs look similar to this:

```
<div data-id="XX">
 Some Serial Number
</div>
```

There is an input field that triggers on textChange and searches for the string in the set of divs.

I have tried various ways of searching for the string however on ipad most of them feel sluggish.
All the elements start as visible and I want to hide the ones that are not applicable to the search.
This is what I have tried so far:

using contains:
    var txt = $('#searchField').val();

```
$('.product:not(:contains("'+txt+'"))').hide();
```

which takes around 400-500ms to process per request

using a selector based on data-serial-number (i added the serialnumber as a data element as well):

```
$(".product:not([data-serial-number*='" + txt + "'])").hide()
```

which takes around 400ms per request.

I have also tried using a css class to hide elements instead of using .hide() however this made not much of a noticable difference.

In a tutorial I found an extension to the default selectors which seems to be the fastest approach so far:

```
 $.expr[":"].containsNoCase = function(el, i, m) {
                  var search = m[3];
                  if (!search) return false;
                  return eval("/" + search + "/i").test($(el).text());
          };

$('.product:containsNoCase(\'' + txt + '\')').hide();
```

I guess my question is are there any other methods of trying to achieve this search that might be faster? I have tried using .find() but found it to be sluggish as well.

Thanks in advance for looking at this :)

Comment: With a large dataset and an iPad this will always be within the 300-700ms range....wether you use find(), filter(), not() etc....theres likely no way around it.....400ms aint that bad though....

Comment: Yeah maybe I am looking at this the wrong way, maybe I need to restrict responsiveness of the input a little bit so that it feels more intuitive, as it is doing a request on every keystroke

Comment: Oh yeah, I would definitely do it on blur() instead of keyup() or change()...or maybe implement a setTimeout() inside the change function to count 20-50ms between keystrokes before submitting or something of that nature

Comment: using the jquery textChange() plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this...

```
var timeout;
$('#searchField').keyup(function() {
var filter = $(this).val(); 
if(timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
}
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
if(filter.length>0) { 
$('.product').show();
$('.product:not(:contains("'+filter+'"))').hide();
$('.product:contains("'+filter+'"))').show();
} else { $('.product').show();} 
}, 500)
});
```

This way, it only responds after stopping typing for 50ms....then it searches.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/nZFVW/3/)